# Interface enforces event, anything enforce handlers?

Tags: c#

Given:

```
public delegate void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs<SomeArgs> e)

public interface MyInterface
{
    event MyHandler TheEvent;
} 

class MyClass:MyInterface
{
    public event MyHandler TheEvent;         
}

class TheProblemClass:FrameworkElement //, IPossibleInterface?
{
    public MyClass Instance1{get;set;}
    public MyClass Instance2{get;set;}

    //You used an instance of MyClass, now you must handle Instance1.TheEvent
    //You used another instance of MyClass, now you must handle must handle Instance2.TheEvent
    //...for any instance of MyClass, MUST handle TheEvent

}
```

Ok, so I intend for other devs to create their own classes using instances of `MyClass`. Any way to enforce the scope that declares an instance of `MyClass` to also handle the event?

Comment: add constructor to  MyClass(MyHandler  handler)

Comment: Why the event would ought to be handled in a mandatory way in the first place ? If I've nothing to do (to care) about what happens it would make me write an empty handler for nothing.

Comment: @Sehnsucht TheEvent is essentially a custom 'changed' notification, so unless TheProblemClass subscribes, it won't know MyClass has been doing work.

Comment: So it's up to the one writing that class to handle the event if it choose so (in the same way it's up to people to properly dispose `IDisposable`)